# Redirect/Bad Gateway issues with Wordpress and Plesk Site Preview

Tags: php, wordpress, plesk

I'm facing some weird problems when trying to view my Wordpress website via Plesk site preview.

The preview url looks as follows:
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/plesk-site-preview/example.com/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/

I already changed the base url of Wordpress (Settings -> General) to the url above.

Now, when accessing the url I can see the home page. But when I try to access any subsite, it results in an redirect loop:

```
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.
```

When I try to access http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/plesk-site-preview/example.com/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/wp-admin/, I get an 502 Bad Gateway error.

The only way I was able to get it working properly was to set the servers ip in my /etc/hosts file to example.com. But thats not an option because I have to send the preview url to my client and it should work out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have access to the Website Preview Settings mentioned in Oleg's answer.

But I found a workaround using xip.io.

Simply create a domain alias called

```
example.com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xip.io
```

within Plesk and you're able to access the website without setting up any DNS records. I don't know why, but without the domain alias it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Set preview mode to "Quick Preview on a domain name in Plesk" with some domain which can be resolved

https://:8443/admin/server/preview-domain-settings

[image: plesk site preview]

You will get url like:

```
http://example.tld.10-52-80-183.a10-52-80-183.qa.plesk.ru/
```

Set this url in WordPress settings.

Comment: I guess that would work, but unfortunately I don't have access to these settings. But thank you anyway.